# Passing params with onchange in Rails 4.2.4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onchange

As a rails and js newb I am having some serious trouble with this one. I have read so many threads trying to figure this out but I just can't find the answer, and I am sure it's something simple.

I am trying to pass the selected id from a collection_select to a param and I just can't seem to get there.
Here is the code:

```
<%= collection_select :bid_month_select, :month_id, BidMonth.all.order("id DESC"),
                    :id, :year_month, {}, {class: "form-control",
                    :onchange => "location.href = '#{user_bids_path(:bid_month_id => :id)}'"} %>
```

The param is being passed as "id". I know that is because it's a symbol. I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to pass the actual id of the selected month from the dropdown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm with the same issue, have you figured it out?

Comment: I have not. I gave up for the time being due to lack of time. Eventually I'll keep working on it.